# Do I still the api-ms redirect DLLs in Windows 10/.NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

Every application I publish as self-contained with .NET 6 and before outputs a large set of **api-ms*** assemblies/DLLs. While I understand for what reason they are here, I thought the original reason was that API call from former P/Invokes are redirected to newer API calls.

I assumed that increasing the RuntimeIdentifier to **win10** or even higher versions, like **net5.0-windows10.0.22000.0** gets rid of them but they are still there.

*What is the reason why they are still there even in never version and can I safely delete them?
I would also be nice if there would be a good reference to read about. I'm not sure if something is written in "Windows Internals" or if I missed it.*

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Suggest a feature to remind them about it.

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you delete them?

Comment: @PMF: Honestly I didn't try. I didn't want to get unexpected results unless I know for sure I can delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant advised I filed an issue on the dotnet/runtime repository and got an answer (see: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/65692).

In short obviously since >= Windows 7 they are not necessary anymore but are still there when publishing the app for some internal reasons. Nevertheless I was told that they are working on it to get rid of them.